# Como puedo saber desde que formulario llame a un componente?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Tengo creado un componente personalizado que es un TEdit de la siguiente forma:

**TDBCodBanco = class(TDBEdit)**

El cual instalo como un paquete en mi Delphi.

El cual uso en muchos formularios de mi sistema ya sea para inserción y/o consulta.
El problema es que ahora me piden que bloquee algunos bancos para las tareas de inserción y son aprox. 50 formularios que utilizan ese campo para insertar datos de bancos a la base de datos.

Como podría saber desde que formularios estoy llamando a ese componente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si colocas el componente dentro de un formulario en el editor de Delphi en tiempo de diseño, podrías valerte de la propiedad `Owner`, que siempre va a ser el formulario.

Por ejemplo:

```
procedure TDBCodBanco.Loaded();
begin
  Self.Enabled :=    (Owner.Name = 'TfrmAutorizada')
                  or (Owner.Name = 'TfrmAutorizada2');
end;
```

Si los creas *"a mano"* en código, podrías tomar como convención siempre establecer como `Owner` el formulario, y llamar a un método que haga la auto-configuración luego de establecerlo.